# C# to database (textboxes)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I want to use my textboxes to send data to my database.

The problem is that he doesn't know `loonberekening.tblWerknemer`, I always get

> incorrect syntax near 'tblWerknemer'

Here is a picture of my tables: http://gyazo.com/1a92845f51f56ef37e9ae3adf3f23a7c

```
string database = (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\gip_stap_2\loonberekening.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
string werknemergegevens = "insert into loonberekening.tblWerknemer (naam,voornaam) values ('"+txtNaam.Text+"','"+txtVoornaam.Text+"');";
SqlConnection cnnLoonberekening = new SqlConnection(database);
SqlCommand scmdLoon = new SqlCommand(werknemergegevens, cnnLoonberekening);
SqlDataReader check;

try{
    cnnLoonberekening.Open();
    check = scmdLoon.ExecuteReader();
    MessageBox.Show("Opgeslagen");
    while (check.Read())
    {
    }
}catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: try `loonberekening.dbo.tblWerknemer`?

Comment: Hello SQL injection. Please parameterize your SQL query.

Comment: im going to use dutch for all my variable names from now on

Comment: I suggest you use doubles wherever you can so you can have double dutch :-)

Comment: change loonberekening.tblWerknemer to loonberekening..tblWerknemer

Answer (score 0):

Try `"insert into loonberekening.dbo.tblWerknemer"`

also as an aside look into parameterisation of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Either add `;InitialCatalog=loonberekening` to the end of the connection string to specify the database or add a schema name to the query: `loonberekening.dbo.tblWerknemer`.

- There will be nothing to read back from an insert as you appear to be attempting
- You need to use an `SQLCommand` to prevent what will happen if you run your code with a `'` anywhere in the textbox. (SQL Injection)

Comment: i cannot find ;InitialCatalog in #c and i dont understand "add a schema name to the query"

Comment: Add it: `string database = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\gip_stap_2\loonberekening.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;InitialCatalog=loonberekening";`

Comment: now im getting an error :An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'initialcatalog'.

Comment: nvm im getting this error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'integra‌​ted security'.

Answer (score 0):

Try "insert into loonberekening.dbo.tblWerknemer"
or
only  "insert into tblWerknemer"
then rest parts

Answer (score 0):

Try rewrite the query as `insert into dbo.tblWerknemer ...`, because `loonberekening` is the database name and `dbo.tblWerknemer` is the actual table name

Also try to use parametrized query instead of directly passing values to prevent sql injection.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-parameterizing-your-sql-queries-the-right-way-to-query-a-database/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 string database = (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\gip_stap_2\loonberekening.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
string werknemergegevens = "insert into tblWerknemer (naam,voornaam) values (@Naam,@Voornaam)";
using(SqlConnection cnnLoonberekening = new SqlConnection(database))
{

SqlCommand scmdLoon = new SqlCommand(werknemergegevens, cnnLoonberekening);
    scmdLoon.Parameters.Add("@Naam",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=txtNaam.Text;
    scmdLoon.Parameters.Add("@Voornaam",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=txtVoornam.Text;
    scmdLoon.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```